# JQuery reload/refresh/re-render select control

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following functions to do a search in the options of a select using an input text:

This function does the search whenever a key is pressed:

```
$( 'input#id_nit_del_cliente' ).keyup(function(e){
          var nit = $('input#id_nit_del_cliente').val();
          if(nit==='')
          {
            console.log("vacio:"+nit);
          }
          else {
            console.log("nit:"+nit);
            $("#id_cliente_idcliente option:starts-with("+nit+")").attr('selected', true);
            var seleccionado=$("#id_cliente_idcliente option:selected").text();
            console.log("elemento:"+seleccionado);
          }
        });
```

Later i want to do a comparation to know if what i wrote in the input text is the same than a portion of the text contained in one of the options in the select, i do the comparation when "enter key" or "tab key" are pressed:

```
  $( 'input#id_nit_del_cliente' ).keydown(function(e){
          var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
          if (e.keyCode==9||e.keyCode==13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var text=$("#id_cliente_idcliente option:selected").text().split(' ');
            var nit = $('input#id_nit_del_cliente').val();
            console.log("Nit del select:"+text[0]);
            console.log("Nit del text:"+nit);
            if(text[0]===nit)
            {
              $('input#id_codigo_producto').focus();
              console.log("Solo nit:"+text[0]);
            }
            else {
              alert('El cliente no existe');
              $("#id_cliente_idcliente").selectmenu("refresh", true);
              $('input#id_nit_del_cliente').val('');
              $('input#id_nit_del_cliente').focus();
            }
          }
        });
```

All this code works, but when it enters to the "else" of the second function, i manually clean the input text, and write something else, and it works, but at the third time it stops working, thats why i want to reload the select text, because when i press the refresh button of the browser, the select still showing the last selected value, but the search works again, but after two intents it fails again. I can't use any jquery plug-in because the "selects" and all the form controls are auto-generated by a DJango 1.8 ModelForm. I tried that selectmenu("refresh", true) method, but console log shows this:

```
TypeError: $(...).selectmenu is not a function
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<label>Cliente: </label><input id="id_nit_del_cliente" maxlength="13" name="nit_del_cliente" type="text" />
<select id="id_cliente_idcliente" name="cliente_idcliente">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">123456-k - Nombre: Esteban José López Ambrosio</option>
<option value="2">4543243-5 - Nombre: Nombre1 Apellido1</option>
<option value="3">843453-5 - Nombre: Persona Prueba Probando Fecha</option>
</select>
<label for="id_codigo_producto">Código: </label><input id="id_codigo_producto" maxlength="25" name="codigo_producto" type="text" />
```

I also use this code, i found it somewhere here in stackoverflow (this is not important, is working):

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
      "starts-with": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),
        term = data[3];
        // first index is 0
        return text.indexOf(term) === 0;
        },
      "ends-with": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),
        term = data[3];
        // last index is last possible
        return text.lastIndexOf(term) === text.length - term.length;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You want the select to go back to this `<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>` option?

Comment: @StephanSutter Actually, yes, i want to do that, do you think that will solve my problem? Because I only thougth that the Select was stuck and the selected option didn't matter, but if you have a solution i will try it :D

Comment: I don't understand, you said you want to search the options. But why are you only looking for the selected option? Here `var text=$("#id_cliente_idcliente option:selected").text().split(' ');`

Comment: @StephanSutter Probably this isn't the best approach, but that was the first to come to my mind, i'll explain to you:

In the first function if i write something like "123" it will change the selected option wich text starts with that characters, it happens in this part:
$("#id_cliente_idcliente option:starts-with("+nit+")").attr('selected', true);

Later in the second function I use the portion of code that you pasted in your comment. In that function I want to know for example, if "123" is equal to "123456-k".

Comment: So if "123" is not equal to "123456-k", you want to reset the values of the input and select right?

Comment: @StephanSutter Exactly! That's what I want. And also, i want to do that an indefinite number of times, because now the values are not reseted but it shows an alert when values are not equal, but when i search after two alerts are displayed (or the condition isn't true after two tries), search stops working and Select just don't change the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the start of your javascript

`var selectDefault = $("#id_cliente_idcliente").html();`

And then in your else statement, remove this

`$("#id_cliente_idcliente").selectmenu("refresh", true);`

Then add this

`$("#id_cliente_idcliente").html(selectDefault);`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I spent like three hours finding a solution. I'm a noob with JQuery and Javascript haha. You are awesome!

Comment: @masozow That's where we all start. Good luck!